# PHP extract pieces from url using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I've stored a URL in a variable $url. $url can be:

```
/panel
/panel/<pages>
/panel/<XX>
/panel/<XX>/<pages>
```

Where:

```
panel is a fixed string
<pages> is an aribtary string
<XX> is a number (1 to infinite digits)
```

How can I explode and get out $number (if it exists) and $page (if it exists) using a regular expression in php?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? It'll help us assess what help you need to learn, rather than just giving you the answer.

Comment: Why do you need regular expressions? As you mentioned, you can just [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the variable with delimiter `/` and check each part separately. Regex is an overkill here.

Comment: "How can i explode and get out $number (if exists) ..." *fun fact:* you normally cannot explode and get out afterwards :)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter :O .... Rated M!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use: `^/panel(?:/(\d*)/?(\w*)/?)?$`

```
$strs = array(
    '/panel'
    ,'/panel/pages'
    ,'/panel/69'
    ,'/panel/69/pages'
);
foreach($strs as $str)
{
    preg_match('#^/panel(?:/(\d*)/?(\w*)/?)?$#',$str,$matches);
    list($orig,$number,$pages) = array_pad($matches,3,false);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(compact('orig','number','pages'));
    echo "</pre>";
}
/* OUTPUT:

Array
(
    [orig] => /panel
    [number] =>
    [pages] =>
)

Array
(
    [orig] => /panel/pages
    [number] =>
    [pages] => pages
)

Array
(
    [orig] => /panel/69
    [number] => 69
    [pages] =>
)

Array
(
    [orig] => /panel/69/pages
    [number] => 69
    [pages] => pages
)

*/
```

Comment: Doesn't OP want to match `/panel/pages/69` instead of `/panel/69/pages`?

Comment: @Broxzier the top of their post says `/panel/<XX>/<pages>` at the bottom of the first code block, so no

Comment: @Alvins No worries, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
^/panel(/[a-zA-Z]+)?(/\d+)?$
```

Matches:

```
/panel
/panel/23
/panel/apple
/panel/apple/1234
```

Doesn't match:

```
/panel/
/panel/23/apple
/panel/apple/123/12
/panel/apple/pear
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regex simply returns `true` if there is a match, and `false` if not. There's a ton of tutorials about how to use regular expressions with PHP, and how to get the part you want out of it. In this case, `$1` will hold the page name, and `$2` will hold the page number.

Comment: what tool did u use to draw the representation of the regex ?

Comment: @SAnDAnGE https://www.debuggex.com/r/GtWGLRuEmiRyv5Ga

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this can work:

```
$url = "/panel/33/asdasd-asdasd";

preg_match('/\/panel\/?([^\/]*)\/?([^\/]*)/i', $url, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Basically expressions followed by ? or * will match only if they are present

Answer (score 0):

What appears from the question is that you just need to find out the second segment in your url in case that segment is a number.

So you can do this:

Find out the second segment -> check if it a number -> in case your test is positive (i.e. it is a number) -> you have already obtained what you want.

Answer (score 0):

New to regexp, but try this:

```
$urls = array();
$urls[] = "/panel";
$urls[] = "/panel/something";
$urls[] = "/panel/12";
$urls[] = "/panel/42/something else";

foreach($urls as $url)
{
    echo "evaluating: '$url'";
    preg_match("|/panel(?:/)?([0-9]*)?(?:/)?(.*)?|",$url,$matches);
    echo "<pre>"; 
    var_dump($matches);
    echo "</pre>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/995fb230d002377fc2832a8b3d13b1479a8981b7)

```
function parsePath($url) {
  $number = NAN;
  $page = '';
  $found_number = false;
  $found_page = false;

  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  $pathArr = [];

  if (isset($parsed['path']))
    $pathArr = explode('/', $parsed['path']);

  foreach ($pathArr as $path) {
    if (is_numeric($path) && !$found_number) {
      $number = $path;
      $found_number = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!empty($path) && preg_match('/[^(panel)]/', $path) && !$found_page) {
      $page = $path;
      $found_page = true;
      continue;
    }
  }
  echo "Parsed Url = { Number: $number, Page: '$page' }\n";
}

parsePath('http://www.google.com/panel/123/page1');
parsePath('http://www.google.com/panel/page1/123');
parsePath('http://www.google.com/panel/123');
parsePath('http://www.google.com/panel/page1');
parsePath('http://www.google.com');
```

Result:

```
Parsed Url = { Number: 123, Page: 'page1' }
Parsed Url = { Number: 123, Page: 'page1' }
Parsed Url = { Number: 123, Page: '' }
Parsed Url = { Number: NAN, Page: 'page1' }
Parsed Url = { Number: NAN, Page: '' }
```